# How can I constrain T in Rust to accept only numeric types?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to create some structs that have a property of a generic type T. This generic type will be used for calculations, so I want T to be all kind of numeric types such as i32, u32, f32, uf32, i64 etc. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not depend on the traits you actually need, in addition to perhaps the `Copy` trait? That will cover numbers and number-like objects devised in the future (think complex numbers or with non-standard sizes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what the [num-traits crate](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) can be used for. The [`Num` trait](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num_traits/trait.Num.html) is implemented for all numeric types.

This ensures your generic type `T` has all of the expected numeric operators, `Add`, `Sub`, `Mul`, `Div`, `Rem`, can be partially equality checked via `PartialEq`, it also exposes a value for `1` and `0` for `T`.

You can see how the crate implements the trait [here](https://github.com/rust-num/num/blob/e7df30bac45795d144e8b33c6bbc97c22c949731/traits/src/lib.rs#L129-L142):

```
int_trait_impl!(Num for usize u8 u16 u32 u64 isize i8 i16 i32 i64);
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. However, there must be a way in the Rust language itself to implement this right? In C# for example you have the where keyword that constrains the accepted types. The crate itself must have been using some language feature to do this.

Comment: @Midas They defined the trait `Num` and implemented it for all the standard numeric types. You could make your own trait `Num` and implement it for all numeric types, but you may as well use the crate.

Comment: Just look at what the crate does, they're only cooking with water